# Querying encoded XML within unencoded XML column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sqlxml

I have table with an XML column which looks like the following. The XML column has some encoded XML inside unencoded XML.

```
OrderID    UserDefXML
      1    <Order><OrderDetail><LineItem><ItemName>XYZ</ItemName><Custominfo> &lt;PrimaryName&gt;STACKOVERFLOW &lt;/PrimaryName&gt;</Custominfo></LineItem></OrderDetail></Order>
```

I need to extract all the rows which has `PrimaryName LIKE 'STACK%'`. What should the query be like for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the encoded XML string -the content of `Custominfo` element- to XML data type first, for example :

```
SELECT t.*, x.lineItem.value('Custominfo[1]','varchar(max)') 'CustomInfo'
FROM YourTableName t
CROSS APPLY t.UserDefXML.nodes('/Order/OrderDetail/LineItem') as x(lineItem)
WHERE 
  CONVERT(XML, x.lineItem.value('Custominfo[1]','varchar(max)')).value('PrimaryName[1]','varchar(max)') 
  LIKE 'STACK%'
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e426/2)</kbd>**

**Output :**

[image]